# AngularDart - How to keep the floating label aligned to the left of glyph in MaterialAutoSuggestInputComponent?

Tags: angular-components, angular-dart

Consider the following `material-auto-suggest-input` with 
in addition to other attributes, these `[label]="'Leader'"`, `[floatingLabel]="true"` and `[leadingGlyph]="'search'"` and empty value:

[image]

When a value is entered in the input the label fluctuates upwards as follows:

[image]

Rather than being aligned with the entered value to the right of the glyph, I would like ***it to be left aligned, exactly on starts the glyph and the underlined line***. Like this:

[image]

I didn't find any mixins that could help me. How could you implement this left alignment?